# OBD Connector to Arduino

Tags: hardware

I bought [an OBD connector](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9911) from Sparkfun to try to connect to my vehicle via arduino.

I'm just beginning and am not sure if I can just connect the connector pics to the arduino directly, or if there is some other required hardware?

Does anyone know if I can connect directly and why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I briefly read up on this subject and I found out this:

It seems like there's a protocol called *J1850*. There's no native support on the Arduino for that, but you might be able to do something bit-banging if you can find the specifications for this protocol. If you do this, I'd advise accessing the registers directly and skipping the `digitalRead()` command.

There are a few protocols in use, so it is hard to know without knowing the car you drive to even tell what the car will send.

*[More on this topic...](http://pinoutsguide.com/CarElectronics/car_obd2_pinout.shtml)*

Anyway, it seems like you need a chip to use with this. [Sparkfun also sells a breakout board for the STN1110 OBD-II to UART chip](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9555) *([tutorial)](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/obd-ii-uart-hookup-guide)*. I couldn't really find anything else besides [this](http://arduinodev.com/hardware/obd-kit/).

Anyway, you probably need another chip to do this work. The Arduino isn't meant to do all of these protocols, and the OBD isn't UART-compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the help!   I also found an pdf here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=uvPxU-vjLo27oQTW2YDgCA&url=https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/millerrv/Ryan_Miller/Projects/Entries/2010/12/21_Arduino_OBD-II_Interface_files/CS497_presentation_miller.pdf&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEguP_tgEU-i6_6MbNqOoXj9er37A&sig2=1teeC0hht_QSnBZAc9JrBQ

Comment: @mECH interesting! It looks like they used the MC33290 and bit banging to do this. I don't have time now to look into it more now, but a library with hardware timers would be helpful...